# maximizing using lagrangian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier, economics, utility

So I have a question from my quiz. I don't want a specific answer but a help or guidence.
My objective function is F(x,y)=x+4y and my subject is I-Px*x-Py*y=0 where I,Px and Py are both positive integers. When I am trying to use lagrangian and try to maximize objective function I just can't but I don't know why. How can I maximize this function.

Comment: It works. The result is $P_y=4\cdot P_x$

Comment: But both Py and Px is a constant number. How can I reach maximized f(x,y) here?

Comment: A reply is welcomed.

Comment: You have an objective function, and a constraint. Do you remember where the lagrangian comes in?

Answer (score 0):

Using lagrange multipliers and differentiating, we get
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=1+\lambda P_x=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=5+\lambda P_y=0.$$
Unless $P_x$ and $P_y$ take on special values, this does not have a solution.  This indicates we do not have an interior optimum and we must check the boundary conditions. This means checking if $x=0$ or $y=0$.  Depending on prices, it will be one or the other, except in the case where the answer is indeterminant.